# Getting historical values from higher timeframes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've built a custom indicator and I've plotted them using dots on top of candles. When a dot meets a certain criteria with another dot, I draw a trend line connecting them. That works..

What I would like to do is augment these lines from higher timeframes since I typically trade on the 5m. Meaning, if these dots on the daily timeframe meet the criteria, I'd like the line to be drawn on the daily but I should be able to see as well when I'm on the 5m timeframe.

I've tried leveraging `request.security` like so..

`dots = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", calcDots(high), gaps = barmerge.gaps_on, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)`

And when I plot dots I'll get only the single dot from the daily only on the 5m view I'm on.. which is fine. But when I go do `dots[1]` it's not the actual previous dot from the daily chart. Perhaps my understand of `request.security` isn't right and there's something else I need to do to access or run my code against that higher timeframe data?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct to use the `reuqest.security()` function. The catch is, the historical values of `dots` will be filled on your chart's timeframe. So, `dots[1]` will refer to its previous value on your chart's timeframe.

Let's look at two examples where we request the **daily** open price while we are on the 6-hour timeframe. So, we will have a new value on every 4th candle.

### Example 1 (barmerge.lookahead_on):

```
[daily_1, daily_2] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [open, open[1]], gaps = barmerge.gaps_on, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

| Variable | Bar #1 | Bar #2 | Bar #3 | Bar #4 | Bar #5 | Bar #6 | Bar #7 | Bar #8 | Bar #9 | Bar #10 | Bar #11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| daily_1 | 16978.38 | na | na | na | 17093.53 | na | na | na | 16886.81 | na | na |
| daily_1[1] | na | 16978.38 | na | na | na | 17093.53 | na | na | na | 16886.81 | na |
| daily_2 | 17165.39 | na | na | na | 16978.38 | na | na | na | 17093.53 | na | na |

In this example, `daily_1[1]` will follow `daily_1` on the next bar. So, its value will refer to `daily_1`'s value on the previous bar on your chart's timeframe. `daily_2` will refer to the previous day's open price. It is what you think `daily_1[1]` should do.

### Example 2 (barmerge.lookahead_off):

```
[daily_1, daily_2] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [open, open[1]], gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

---

| Variable | Bar #1 | Bar #2 | Bar #3 | Bar #4 | Bar #5 | Bar #6 | Bar #7 | Bar #8 | Bar #9 | Bar #10 | Bar #11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| daily_1 | 16978.38 | 16978.38 | 16978.38 | 16978.38 | 17093.53 | 17093.53 | 17093.53 | 17093.53 | 16886.81 | 16886.81 | 16886.81 |
| daily_1[1] | 17165.39 | 16978.38 | 16978.38 | 16978.38 | 16978.38 | 17093.53 | 17093.53 | 17093.53 | 17093.53 | 16886.81 | 16886.81 |
| daily_2 | 17165.39 | 17165.39 | 17165.39 | 17165.39 | 16978.38 | 16978.38 | 16978.38 | 16978.38 | 17093.53 | 17093.53 | 17093.53 |

This example shows how the historical values are being filled.

### Note:

This is a real example.

```
Ticker: BINANCE:BTCBUSD
Timeframe: 6h
Bar #1: Fri 02 Dec '22 00:00 UTC
Bar #11: Sun 04 Dec '22 12:00 UTC
```

You can check out the values if you simply add the following:

```
plotchar(daily_1, "daily_1", "")
plotchar(daily_1[1], "daily_1[1]", "")
plotchar(daily_2, "daily_2", "")
```