# Getting issue in fetching higher timeframe histogram color in lower time frame

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to fetch Day Timeframe histogram color in 15 minutes timeframe in custom indicator.initially it shows correct color of day timeframe histogram, but if there is in price movement in lower timeframe day histogram color status get changed in indicator which is incorrect. ideally in actual day time frame histogram color is different.
for example :

DAY TIMEFRAME : Histogram color is Green

15 Minute Time Frame : We are fetching Day TF Histogram color in 15minute timeframe in custom indicator. Initially it displays Green but if candle color/Price Red/move down in 15minute timeframe it displays Day histogram status red but in actual DAY TIMEFRAME it is Green.

My Requirement is to fetch actual DAY TIMEFRAME histogram color in indicator without changing its original color. it will get changed if there is a change in Actual Day Timeframe Histogram color.

How we can achieve this?
[image for Isuue facing on Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avHh1.png)

```
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line??", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line??", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(color.green, "Above???Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above") //#26A69A
col_fall_above = input(color.red, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above") //#f80000
col_grow_below = input(color.green, "Below?Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below") //#26A69A
col_fall_below = input(color.red, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below") //#f80000

col_grow_above_ = color.green//, "Above???Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above") //#26A69A
col_fall_above_ = color.red//, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above") //#f80000
col_grow_below_ = color.green//, "Below?Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below") //#26A69A
col_fall_below_ = color.red//, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below") //#f80000

// Getting data from 1Day timeframe
[macd_1d, signal_1d, hist_1d] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", getMACDData(src, fast_length, slow_length, signal_length, sma_source, sma_signal))

// Plotting histograms with different conditions
histColor_1d_ = hist_1d >= 0 ? (hist_1d[1] < hist_1d ? col_grow_above_ : col_fall_above_) : (hist_1d[1] < hist_1d ? col_grow_below_ : col_fall_below_)

plot(0.0000, title="1D Histogram", color=histColor_1d_, linewidth=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

`hist_1d[1]` will not give you the previous `hist_1d`'s value from the daily timeframe. It will give you the previous `hist_1d`'s value on the previous bar - your chart. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74751302/7209631) answer for more detailed explanation.

You can get the color from the `security()`as well. Calculate the color on your timeframe and pass it to the `security()` function to get the color on the 1D timeframe.

```
hist_color = hist >= 0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above_ : col_fall_above_) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below_ : col_fall_below_)

// Getting data from 1Day timeframe
[macd_1d, signal_1d, hist_1d, histColor_1d_] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [getMACDData(src, fast_length, slow_length, signal_length, sma_source, sma_signal), hist_color])
```